# Tag soup: [dijkstra]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-question

A few weeks ago, the question [Dijkstra-like routing algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44195/9357) introduced the [dijkstra](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dijkstra) tag, intending to refer to Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm.

Now, the question [Infix-to-postfix parser using Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46136/9357) has been posed, and Jamal has added the [dijkstra](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dijkstra) tag to it.

Of course, Dijkstra's [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) has nothing to do with Dijkstra's more well known [shortest-path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm), other than the fact that they were invented by the same person.  I don't think that there is any utility in having the two questions share the [dijkstra](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dijkstra) tag.

How would you clean up the mess?  There are currently 8 questions with the tag.

Comment: Yeah, I was also a little hasty with adding this tag.  I agree that we can get rid of it.

Comment: @Jamal: The tag still exists, and is used for new questions. Nothing in the tag wiki indicates that it should not be used. Perhaps the tag should be removed now, or at least clearly marked as deprecated.

Comment: @MartinR A standard procedure is to also request a tag blacklist from the CMs, which is also why we no longer get crappier tags. I can run this by the other mods, especially if they’ve never gone though such a procedure before.

Comment: @Jamal: There are only 14 questions tagged with [dijkstra], so perhaps a first step could be to remove that tag from those questions (and add [pathfinding] where appropriate)?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### We don't need a dijkstra-specific pathfinding tag.

For questions about [pathfinding](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinding), use the [pathfinding](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinding) tag. (Duh!) This includes Dijkstra's pathfinding algorithm, as well as A* an others. (We don't have an [a-star](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-star) tag that I know of and I don't think we need one either)

I believe [Dijkstra-like routing algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44195/dijkstra-like-routing-algorithm) has more in common with [Path finding - again](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30606/how-can-i-improve-my-a-pathfinding-code-again) than what it has in common with non-pathfinding Dijkstra questions

As for [Infix-to-postfix parser using Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46136/9357), it has the [parsing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) which tells more about what the question is about than any [dijkstra](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dijkstra)-tag can do.

#### Summary

For Dijkstra questions about pathfinding, use [pathfinding](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinding). For other algorithms invented by Dijkstra, use tags that summarizes what the algorithm is *about*, not for who invented it.

Answer (score 6):

"The [dijkstra](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dijkstra) tag has no wiki summary".

I don't trust a tag with no summary: I don't trust that people know what how it's meant to be used.